# Spotlight isn't working?

Tags: light

I'm following a tutorial (you know the one) and the spotlight isn't working.. Also, I think somethings wrong with my flooring because ever since I added it in it didn't have any light hitting it? It may just be the spotlight full stop though.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an Output Node for the lamp.

You can insert them manually: Just add an **Emission** and a **Lamp Output** nodes.

[image]